# Best way to load 100 images in one page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my website there is a webpage where there are 100 images and it is inelegant to see the images that are loaded one at a time from the browser.

Is there some way to get it more elegant and nice to see ?

Comment: also interested in this question.

Comment: images are tiny 18x18 px

Comment: Use [css sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Comment: I can't use css sprite because images are loaded dinamically

Comment: What difference does that make

Comment: I can't assemble these 100 images in one image and then using css sprite tecnique.

Comment: @xRobot what do you mean you can't?

Comment: @xRobot Provide sample code on how your loading these dynamically, and I'm sure we'll know a way of doing it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [**Lazy Load**](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) the images, which means they are only loaded when displayed on the browser. This works by simply using the following:

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload();
```

However, if the images which will be visible on page load are very large file size, theres not much you can do to prevent this.

An idea I have used before to make this more user-friendly is to place each `img` element in `div` which has a background image of an [ajax loader](http://ajaxload.info/). This at least gives the appearance that something is loading. Then once the image is loaded, this will overlay the loading image.

---

**EDIT:** Seeing your [latest comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735366/best-way-to-load-100-images-in-one-page/10735400#comment13946542_10735366), if you are using very small images, as [@afaf12](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10735480/370103) has pointed out, using [**CSS Sprites**](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) would be a suitable solution. A lot of large sites, including StackOverflow, make use of these. It means rather than 100 HTTP Requests being made for all the images, 1 HTTP Request is made (ie. 1 image download), and then CSS is used to position this image in different places.

There are various different [CSS Sprite generators](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/) also available to prevent you from the laborious task of making this yourself:

Comment: a Sprite of 100 18x18 images will take like a few kilobytes.. after that all the images are instantly ready. lazyloading that is just overkill

Comment: @Esailija I agree, hence my edit after I saw the OP's comments

Comment: css sprint is a great idea but I can't use it because images are loaded dinamically

Comment: @xRobot Please provide more information regarding this in your question, and perhaps some sample code

Answer (score 2):

Since images are very small, this could be a situation where css sprites are useful.

Instead of having 100+ small images, you have 1 large.

When you want to show a specific image, you have to specify background coordinates, for example:

```
div#div1 {background-position:0px -100px}
```

Comment: I can't use css sprite because images are loaded dinamically in my case.

Comment: i also agree with a big sprite of 1800x1800. what do you mean dynamically? you can create it just once with img = new Image(); and apply it with css/js wherever you want.

Comment: @vlzvl 1800x1800 will hold 10000 18x18 images. 1800x18 is sufficient for 100 18x18 images

Answer (score 2):

One way to make it look more pleasing is to make the images fade in when they have been loaded:

```
$('img').css('opacity', '0.0').load(function(){
  $(this).animate({'opacity': '1.0'});
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/gzFFN/

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-appear/

jQuery appear event that is triggered when objects "appear" i.e. become visible on screen.

Create containers for all the images, and only load the actual images when they become visible on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting solution can be found on this stack link. It is for all content but the code provided in an answer can be applied to image loading as well. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642142/how-to-synchronize-web-site-content-while-loading-page)